# MS Access - Split the database into two versions (user and admin)

Tags: ms-access

everybody. 
I have such a pretty strong problem - namely. I have created a database in which I have forms, tables, queries and other miracles that make 'Access' available to us. I would now like to release the database to a few users to test their data (when writing the database, I mean forms, not access to all the benefits of "Accessa"). I can't divide the database properly so that it spits out the initial form for the user ONLY (in my case it's a login form, but I don't think it matters any more). So the user clicks on the "Accessa" icon on the network drive and opens a network window, he is not interested in anything else. He shouldn't see the tables, the 'Accessa' toolbar or anything else. I know that there is an option to divide the database into: external and internal (the one from which we share becomes one of them). This is not exactly what I'm talking about, and if that's the case, I haven't found a description of how to use it in the situation that interests me. Why? Because, for example, in the future there will be one field in one of the tables - let's say that the field is called "test" in the "ABC" table. Then I would like this field to be included in the '123' form. I am looking for a relatively dynamic solution. I know that there is a

```
DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon" command, accToolbarNo
```

- but this does not solve the form update problem. I know that the best practice is to do something once, and properly - but life verifies. Additionally, I'm aware that there is a "ACCDE" type in saving options, but I don't see its use in my case either.

All in all, after a moment of thinking: I easily divided the database with this option of sharing (we get the frontend: that's all in all, the backend: that's all tables). My problem is the user's access to this frontend - I don't want him to see anything other than a pop-up form when he opens it. And if everything is blocked, how can I update the form in the future with new fields?

My last problem is that I would like to do reports, queries and other wonders in the future, allowing me to operate on the data. Where should I keep them in the future? Theoretically, the frontend will be blocked and there I won't have any options for action, but will it be good practice to keep it on the backend side? Only I have access to it.

Comment: *Please* use some line breaks to structure your question.

Comment: @Andre Just done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does ACCDE remove the toolbar? I used to use Access back when they had MDE files and I am pretty sure they removed the toolbar and prevented access to certain features, but you could still access the tables. We also used Access Runtime which pretty much restricted everything.

I think you should have a file that you develop on (ACCDB), and a then you release a file for users to use (ACCDE).

Also, you can go to File - Options - Current Database and make sure the Display Form field is the name of the Login Form. Scroll down to Navigation and untick Display Navigation Pane. Then change the Ribbon and Toolbar Options.

Comment: Which of these files you wrote about, that I should use it to create reports, queries - I mean specifically this: "I think you should have a file that you develop on (ACCDB)", but then you wrote: "for users to use (ACCDE)." Do you mean a backend file or a completely different one (new, third)? If so, how do you provide it with up-to-date data?

Additionally, on the screenshot I put what I have now, I would like the whole Access "background" to disappear - there is only the form left. 

[1]: https://i.imgur.com/tOsLYCW.png @Vernon007

Comment: Did you have a backend and a front end? Create one access file (ACCDB) that has just your tables in it. Create another access file (ACCDB) and import all of your linked tables to it by going to External Data - Access - Link to the data source by creating a linked table and the browse to the backend file. This file you will use for your development.  Once you want to release a version for users save an ACCDE file that has limited functionality. Your development file and released file are both linked to the back end tables. Your screenshot - Set the forms popup and modal properties to Yes.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I used your solution. I hope it will work well.